# Indoor bicycle tray to preclude the rug from getting wet

Tags: storage, indoor, parking

When I take my bicycle indoors, and there's snow, ice, etc on it, the snow melts and the water runs onto the floor. Long-term water damage to rugs is an issue, and I don't want to leave the bicycle outside, due to fear of it being stolen.

Are there any trays or the like that will collect the melted water and preclude it from getting onto my rug? Extra points if they're cheap.

Comment: Oversized but a cargo mat for an suv or small truck bed

Comment: I like the use of 'preclude' +1 for imaginative wording

Comment: I would look at floor liners for vehicles, as they tend to have upturned edges that will prevent runoff.  The problem is finding one (or maybe two) that is large enough.  But the flooring dept at your local building center should have all sorts of carpet protectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try a Garden Centre, they usually sell a range of trays and they should have something suitable.

An example would be this "[Giant Plus Garden Tray](http://www.garlandproducts.com/giant-plus-garden-tray-black.html)" which at 120cm x 55cm should be big enough to place a bike on.

[image: Garden Tray]

Comment: I think this is the right idea, just be sure to double check that it's big enough. Just looked up some specs and  a medium size roadbike has a wheel base (hub to hub), of about 100cm. The tires would most likely extend past the edge of the mat, but that might not be a problem since water would most likely run down the tire and not drip straight down. Depending on how much room you have it would probably better to have one that's too big rather than too small.

Comment: If you were to use a wall-mount to hang the bike vertically by it's front wheel, a smaller mat could be used.  And you'd probably have an easier time finding a mat big enough.

Answer (score 4):

I use a few cardboard boxes taped together with gaffer's tape.  The tape is waterproof.  2 layers of cardboard (staggered at edges if you're using small boxes) is plenty to make it through a season.  Use the box edges up against a wall to prevent splatter.  If you have uneven floors and the water rolls off of the boxes, fold an edge over to cause it to be shimmed up a bit, keeping the water on top of the cardboard.

My heavily used cardboard is due for replacing now that we've had quite a bit of snow.  No leakage on the hardwood underneath it though, for a few years now.

[image: Bicycle Cardboard Pad]

If I could find one again... I used to have a plastic shipping pallet that was rectangular with a solid bottom and a decent lip on it (3" or so).  I would put cardboard inside (like those cat cardboard circle things) to soak up water, and then the bike on top.  That way there is a guaranteed solid base, and you can still throw away the cardboard layer taking all the road gunk with it.  This might work with Tom's idea if you can find a tray that's deep enough.

Answer (score 2):

On the cheaper side, a tarp or a vinyl tablecloth should do the trick, and be more easily tidied away and stored. Even a decent-weight shower curtain!

Answer (score 1):

My grandparents used to cover their entry way carpets with a [vinyl carpet protector](http://www.homedepot.com/p/ES-Robbins-Clear-27-in-x-10-ft-Vinyl-Ribbed-Runner-184013/204590651?MERCH=REC-_-NavPLPHorizontal1_rr-_-NA-_-204590651-_-N) in the winter. The nice thing about this is that you can roll it up for storage when you aren't using it.

[image]

Comment: Water rolls off of these things everywhere.  The edges are beveled in such a way that chairs can roll on them.  If you have a lot of snow on your bike, this will create a mess.

Comment: I think that it really depends how much water you have dripping off.  If you have snow, it tends to collect and will probably cause quite a puddle and run off.  If you are just out in the rain, there water tends not to collect so much and you might be ok with something like this.

Comment: Good point!  I'm looking at it from a Chicago perspective where I think my bike becomes 50% snow by the time I get home.  :-)